# Returning a json array slice in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, json

Postgres 9.5

Given a table with one field of type `json`, about 700 rows, and where each row has about 4,000 elements in a single array...

my_db_field:

```
[0.44577, 0.4855, 0.45429, 0.54437,...]
[0.45012, 0.48698, 0.45715, 0.55337,...]
[0.47347, 0.49156, 0.46079, 0.56818,...]
[0.4936, 0.49835, 0.46086, 0.58195,...]
[0.51068, 0.50511, 0.46228, 0.59482,...]
```

The [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) show how you can query for a single element inside an array.

```
 SELECT my_db_field->2 AS test FROM my_db_table
```

results:

```
test (of type json)
--------------------
0.4855
0.48698
0.49156
etc.
```

What I would like to do, though, is select multiple elements in the array and return that as an array in the same format the rows are. By multiple, I mean around 300 elements in the array; e.g., from element 0 to element 300. Does Postgres have a nice syntax for such a query?

Comment: I would look at restructuring the schema here.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - anything in particular you had in mind in that regard?

Comment: We don't know enough about your schema and the json field do to it, but essentially create a new table `test_id int, idx int, elem text`. prune the json-array out of the json object and move it to the new table. Then you could just do `SELECT * FROM test JOIN test_array USING ( test_id ) WHERE idx < 300`. JSON is fine for storing, but I'm questioning whether or not you've outgrown its utility at this point.

Comment: I've made my comment an answer if you decide to go down that route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  array_to_json 
        (
           (select  array_agg(my_db_field->n order by n) 
            from    generate_series(0,least(300,json_array_length(my_db_field))-1) gs(n) 
            )
        )

from    my_db_table
```

---

This solution (the original in this answer) most likely does not guarantee the order of the elements

```
select (array(select json_array_elements(my_db_field)))[1:300]
from    my_db_table
```

Comment: Please check........

Comment: Please handle with care, also I assume the elements order will be preserved, I'm afraid it is not guaranteed. I'll have to check it later on.

Comment: Cool! The only issue is this returns each row as an object instead of an array. Seems hacky, but by adding a `json_build_array` function, then the result for each row is an array.  `SELECT   json_build_array((array(select json_array_elements(my_db_field)))[1:300])->0  FROM  my_db_table`

Comment: re: elements order not preserved - hmmm, that would be a concern, although I don't see any dis-ordering right now of return rows or of values inside the arrays.

Comment: Why would the element order not be guaranteed @DuduMarkovitz?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I'm still confused at how it *most likely does not guarantee the order of the elements*, can you explain that?

Comment: @EvanCarroll - It seems reasonable that the internal implementation of **json_array_elements** and **array** will treat elements by their order but their is no **order** clause in this solution and as far as I know there is no guarantee in the documentation for such behaviour. It doesn't different in concept from inserting rows to a table and expecting that a **select** will return the rows in the same order they were inserted.

Comment: ...and 1 more update

Answer (score 9):

In PostgreSQL 12, you can obtain JSONB array slice using the `jsonb_path_query_array` function:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_array('["a","b","c","d","e","f"]', '$[2 to 4]');
 jsonb_path_query_array
------------------------
 ["c", "d", "e"]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know enough about your schema and the json field do to it, but essentially create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE test_array (
  test_id int       REFERENCES test
  idx     smallint,
  elem    text
  PRIMARY KEY (test_id, idx)
);
```

prune the json-array out of the json object and move it to the new table. Then you could just do

```
SELECT * FROM test
JOIN test_array
  USING ( test_id )
WHERE idx < 300
```

JSON is fine for storing, but I'm questioning whether or not you've outgrown its utility at this point.